# MediaWiki <gallery> min-width parameters

Tags: css, image, mediawiki

Amongst other wiki-pages [Arduino#Official_boards - Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arduino#Official_boards) the `<gallery mode="packed">`thumb for **Adruino_Nano.jpg** has a caption that is so narrow that it breaks on the word  **"Nan`<br />`o"**. 
 I know I could rotate the image but, I'm asking if there is a way to force a minimum width of a thumbnail possibly via some *css-style padding* if yes then the MediaWiki gallery page needs to mention what are the acceptable styles and, if not then. 
  Where should I request any new **gallery parameters** or should I file a bug report on phabricator? or ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Answer (score 0):

In CSS you have the property `min-width`.

https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visudet.html#min-max-widths

Comment: Thanx @Albedo0 but, <br /> Mediawiki.org lists this as the forum to ask questions IRT the PROJECT code but there wasn't any documentation of min-width only {max-width}= as an acceptable parameter. :neckbeard: